# Eclipse helios, preferences -> web Servcies -> METRO Preferences -> METRO Runtime Location, which folder should this be?

Tags: web-services, eclipse, runtime, location, java-metro-framework

Eclipse helios, preferences -> web Servcies -> METRO Preferences -> METRO Runtime Location, which folder should this be?  Or which jar(s) is it looking for?

Maybe a simple thing i missed and just couldn't figure this out.
Tried almost all possible folders under c:/glassfishv3 installation, none seemed to work.

Always got this error:
"Selected folder does not contain METRO runtime installation"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on windows it should be `C:\Glassfish3\glassfish`

You can see an example here http://glassfishplugins.java.net/eclipse36/index.html#1